# Is there value in allowing bounties on a small SE site like this?

Tags: discussion

I was looking at the recent and only "featured" question, as it currently stands it was set up 14 days ago and has only been viewed 28 times.

I could understand this stat if maybe the question was on a large SE with a fairly niche title, but this is talking about Google Analytics, something pretty much all webmasters have dealt with at least a little.

I was thinking that this sends out the wrong sort of message, it makes the site feel more dead than it is, which got me to thinking if on smaller sites were questions stay on the front page for longer would it make sense to do away with the notion of bounties.

Or perhaps something could be done to promote it a bit more - maybe a tweet out on the SE twitter account or added as a featured question on the cross promotional ads that go on all the SE sites? I don't know what the qualifiers for inclusion on these things are, but this might be one way to help busy up that section of the site.

Comment: It's not just Google Analytics, but GA on App Engine, which is a smaller set of people. I tried to find an answer to how those cross site questions appear, but the nearest I got was this feature request http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69997/are-the-hottest-questions-necessarily-the-right-ones-to-feature. Anyone else know?

Comment: True that App Engine narrows down the list of people who could help, but the GA part I would have thought would have got enough people viewing the question.  I used that current featured question as an example but my question is more general than that.

Comment: In general this site seems quite quiet, so +1 for the general idea of promoting it. I've got no great ideas though.